# Laravel accessing an eloquent relation with the relationship's classname, rather than the relationship method name itself?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

Using 5.8 and wondering if it's possible to go from a Fully Qualified Name string i.e., `App\Models\WorkflowType` to the string name of the relationship, in this case `workflowType` to access the method on the Model without a bunch of String Fu. My relationship:

```
/**
 * Many-to-One relationship to WorkflowType
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\belongsTo
 */
public function workflowType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(WorkflowType::class, 'workflow_type_uuid', 'workflow_type_uuid');
}
```

Note: just wondering if there's a "laravel" way of doing this that I'm unaware of. I know that I can do this: `Str::camel(str_replace('App\\Models\\', '', $className))`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply call the `belongsTo()` as it's public. You could play around with something like this:

```
$model = WorkflowType::find(1);
$model->belongsTo(SomeOtherType::class);
```

I"m not a 100% sure this will work, as Eloquent does depend on some magic functions.

Comment: Oh yeah. That does work. I'd need to also pass the key is all.